# In WordPress, how do I login user programatically after checking email and username

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to log in a new user using `wp_signon`, but I get the following message: "`Warning: Cannot modify header information – headers already sent ..."`. From what I searched on Google, I need to run this function before any content is returned, but in my case, I need to login the user only after some processing takes place, so what would be a solution to this problem? I've tried putting all processing and login code inside a function named `process` and wrote `add_action( "init", "process" );`, but it doesn't work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: After what processing does the `login` function need be executed? Most of the time you can put it on top and check if a form is submitted, then log them in.

Comment: @Nytrix, thanks for your comment. I need to perform a validation on the fields (in case JavaScript was disabled), and also check whether the chosen username or email are already taken. I also register the user (this part is working). Only then I try to login the user.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment, you still can put that function on top of everything, like this:

```
<?php
    if($_POST["submit"]){
        //peform login
    }
?>
```

Put this on top of all the other functions, when your form looks something like this:

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="username">
    <input type="password" name="password">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

It would work in this case. **Note:** the string at `$_POST["submit"]` needs to be the same as the button's name. So, if it's like this:

```
<input type="submit" name="login">
```

then your php should look like this: `if($_POST["login"]){}`.

*How and why this works: *

Everytime the page loads, it checks if that `form` is set, normally it continues on without performing the action you have after that `if` statement. **But**, when you submit the form, it reload the page and that if statement is `true` and executes your login function, *before* anything else.

*In your case: *

```
<?php
   if($_POST["submit"]){
       wp_signon();   
   }
   //peform your other functions that needs to happen no matter what. 
?>
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm already checking whether the POST fields are set, and only then I perform the processing, registering and login. However, that doesn't seem to work. And, by my understanding, I really need to perform the login in the end of the if statement.

Comment: Have you tried what I suggested? Why do you need to put it before the other code? And again, what code does it **need** to be after? All that you commented, you can do without any problems with `headers` being sent. You are either echoing something before, have `<!doctype html>` before it, or anything else that is listed in many answers about `header already being sent`.

Comment: I understand. Ok, I'll check again. Thanks.

Comment: In case that doesn't help, provide your actual code and come chat with me in my [chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129761/conversation-about-php)